# Finding top-level xml comments using Python's ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm parsing an xml file using Python's ElementTree, like that:

```
et = ElementTree(file=file("test.xml"))
```

test.xml starts with a few lines of xml comments.

Is there a way to get those comments from et?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For ElementTree 1.2.X there is an article on [Reading processing instructions and comments with ElementTree](http://effbot.org/zone/element-pi.htm)
 (http://effbot.org/zone/element-pi.htm).

---

*EDIT:*

The alternative would be using **lxml.etree** which implements the ElementTree API. A quote from [ElementTree compatibility of lxml.etree](http://codespeak.net/lxml/compatibility.html)
:

> **ElementTree ignores comments** and
>   processing instructions when parsing
>   XML, while **etree will read them in** and
>   treat them as Comment or
>   ProcessingInstruction elements
>   respectively.

Comment: unfortunately, there is no CommentHandler in the version that ships with python 2.5

Comment: Also, it is too risky to use internal library stuff, as the code should work with future versions of python.

Comment: Those are legitimate arguments. I edited my answer and added an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

def parseXml (fn):
    try:
        target = ElementTree.TreeBuilder (insert_comments=True)
        parser = ElementTree.XMLParser(target=target, encoding='utf-8')
        et = ElementTree.parse (fn, parser)
    except Exception as e:
        print ("%s: %s" % (fn, str (e)))
        return

    for el in et.getroot ():
        print (el)
```

Same applies to processing instructions (ElementTree.PI), they will be inserted into the resulting structure only if insert_pis=true.

Comment: Note that this requires Python 3.8.