# Is there a way to access the INFO key based on its text in this XML sample?

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to edit the `<INFO key="search_list_ids"><![CDATA[Edit this data]]></INFO>` in this XML sample. I can access the key via the index: `root[3][1].text`, but I want to be able to access the key by text incase the index changes.

I'm using `xml.etree.ElementTree` and have tried `root.findall()` which usually works.

Any ideas?

```
 <SCANTEMPLATE>
        <TITLE>
            <INFO key="title"><![CDATA[RT_Testing_API]]></INFO>
        </TITLE>
        <TARGET>
            <INFO key="scan_selection"><![CDATA[HostBased]]></INFO>
            <INFO key="asset_groups"><![CDATA[All]]></INFO>
        </TARGET>
        <DISPLAY>
            <INFO key="include_vuln_details"><![CDATA[1]]></INFO>
            <INFO key="include_vuln_details_threat"><![CDATA[1]]></INFO>
            <INFO key="include_vuln_details_threat"><![CDATA[1]]></INFO>
            <INFO key="include_vuln_details_impact"><![CDATA[1]]></INFO>
            <INFO key="include_vuln_details_impact"><![CDATA[1]]></INFO>
            <INFO key="include_vuln_details_solution"><![CDATA[1]]></INFO>
            <INFO key="include_vuln_details_vpatch"><![CDATA[1]]></INFO>
            <INFO key="include_vuln_details_results"><![CDATA[1]]></INFO>
        </DISPLAY>
        <FILTER>
            <INFO key="selective_vulns"><![CDATA[custom]]></INFO>
            <INFO key="search_list_ids"><![CDATA[7777777777777777]]></INFO>
            <INFO key="included_os"><![CDATA[ALL]]></INFO>
            <INFO key="status_active"><![CDATA[1]]></INFO>
            <INFO key="status_new"><![CDATA[1]]></INFO>
            <INFO key="status_reopen"><![CDATA[1]]></INFO>
            <INFO key="vuln_active"><![CDATA[1]]></INFO>
            <INFO key="categories_list"><![CDATA[ALL]]></INFO>
        </FILTER>
</SCANTEMPLATE>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you will do. Is it something like `root[3][1].attrib['key']`? Can you show some code you tried?

Comment: How can I edit the ``7777777777777777`` in ``<INFO key="search_list_ids"><![CDATA[7777777777777777]]></INFO>``? ``append()`` is not working

Comment: Why  do you want to use `append()`?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36984278/how-do-i-parse-a-xml-comment-properly-in-python. This may be helpful.

Comment: `<![CDATA[...]]>` is see by xml.etree as comments, so it don't parse it correctly. Depending of your python version, you will have to change parser or implements your own.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. Not an easy solution :-(